# Rails logger, rotate daily and size

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging, production-environment

Is there any way to rotate the log file on daily basis as well as size? If I set 'daily' rotate and size as 20 MB, the log files should be generated as below.

1. production.log => current log file
2. production.log.20151029.1 or production.log.1 => 20 MB
3. production.log.20151028
4. production.log.20151028.1 => 20 MB
5. production.log.20151028.2 => 20 MB

Comment: Seems like generic sysadmin stuff and, as such, belongs to serverfault.

Comment: Duplicate: http://serverfault.com/questions/474941/how-to-rotate-log-based-on-an-interval-unless-log-exceeds-a-certain-size